# Can't compress a recycled bitmap error

Tags: android, bitmap

I've got a "Can't compress a recycled bitmap error" in my app. It happened on the `picture.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fos);` line in my code here:

```
    private void savePicture(byte[] data, String gameId, String folderName ) {
        File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(gameId, folderName);
        if (pictureFile == null){
            Log.error("Error creating media file, check storage permissions.");
            return;
        }

        Bitmap picture = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);

        picture = getResizedBitmap(picture, bitmapWidth, bitmapHeight);

        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);

            picture.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fos);
            fos.close();
            picture.recycle();

            Log.info(">>> CameraActivity: PICTURE SAVED!");

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.error(LibUtil.getStackTrace(e));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.error(LibUtil.getStackTrace(e));
        }
    }

    public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bmp, int newWidth, int newHeight) {
        int width = bmp.getWidth();
        int height = bmp.getHeight();
        float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
        float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
        // CREATE A MATRIX FOR THE MANIPULATION
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        // RESIZE THE BIT MAP
        matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

        // "RECREATE" THE NEW BITMAP
        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                bmp, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);
        bmp.recycle();
        return resizedBitmap;
    }
```

What I find peculiar though is that when I commented the `bmp.recycle();` line, the error is gone. It looks like (IMHO) the `resizedBitmap` and `bmp` are referencing the same bitmap. But I don't know whether it's the right thing to do and there's no memory leak or whatever in my app.

BTW, this code doesn't display the bitmap on any `ImageView` but it just take a picture from the camera periodically behind the scene and save it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the version of createBitmap doesn't always return a new Bitmap. In your case if `resizedBitmap` is equal to `bmp`, you are recycling both (same reference). In your `getResizedBitmap` add

```
 if (resizedBitamp != bmp) {
    bmp.recycle();
 }
```

> But I don't know whether it's the right thing to do and there's no
>   memory leak or whatever in my app.

unrelated to memory leaks.

Comment: IC. I thought it will always return a new image. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why you recycle the bitmap twice? You can't operate on the recycled one. I mean it can't be compressed, recycled again etc. Remove line `bmp.recycle();` it is useless because you later recycle it in the try condition and like I said on the beginning you can't recycle an already recycled bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `bmp.recycle();` from your `getResizedBitmap` method
Because you are calling twice,so either get rid of `recycle()` or move it to after you have done everything that you intend to do with the Bitmap